# Atoroidal closed 3-manifold

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

A 3-manifold $N$ is called atoroidal if any incompressible torus is boundary parallel, i.e. can be isotoped into the boundary. To me, this definition assumes that $N$ has boundary, but I have read a number of times "an atoroidal closed 3-manifold" (eg in the hyperbolisation conjecture, see Hatcher's [Classification of 3-manifolds](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/Papers/3Msurvey.pdf)).

If $N$ is closed, what does it mean that $N$ is atoroidal?

Comment: It contains no incompressible torus?

Comment: You forgot to assume compactness. The definition allows manifolds with empty boundary, in which case the condition says that $N$ contains no 2-sided incompressible tori.

Comment: That's absolutely true, I was thinking of a compact, connected, orientable manifold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the exact definitions either (a) the manifold contains no embedded incompressible torus or (b) the fundamental group contains no $\mathbb{Z}^2$ subgroup. Some people assume that atoroidal includes (c) irreducible (and boundary irreducible).

On page nine of Hatcher's survey, he means (a).